# Flour contaminated by raw pork juices

Tags: food-safety, flour, pork

The pack of pork I bought was leaky, and some of the juices soaked into a pack of flour. I'm wondering whether the flour is still safe to cook with.

What I'm thinking:

1. The flour will be baked before eating, thus killing any bacteria.
2. Flour is dry, not a suitable environment for the bacteria, they will be dead before I even use the flour in a week or two.

On the other hand, I don't want to get sick over a 1€ pack of flour.
Should I throw it away, or is it safe to consume?

Comment: I really think you answered your own question.  The value of the flour is trivial compared to the risk.  If you were looking at going hungry or losing a substantial supply, then exploring ways to save part of the pack might be an option, but that is really not the case it seems.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Throw it away, it's not worth risking health issues over such a cheap staple. While the flour was originally dry, the pork juice introduced moisture into it, providing a much better breeding ground for bacteria.

Your concern should not be (just) the bacteria, but also the much hardier toxins that they produce--those could easily give you food poisoning, and normal cooking times and temperatures are very unlikely to adequately destroy them.

Comment: As a general rule, the toxins produced are often just proteins (Ex. Botulism toxin). To sufficiently destroy proteins so that they're not toxic, you need to heat them far above the "burn" temperature of almost any food - if you don't know the specific proteins, you probably need to hit autoclave temperatures to be sure. At that point you have a nice charred pile of ash instead of whatever you were cooking.

Comment: I also want to add that we do know bacteria can survive in flour so it's not really safe to consume flour raw anyway; raw flour is dangerous beyond just being a choking hazard.

Comment: I wasn't aware that those toxins would appear in flour. I thought they were a result of the meat decaying, and wouldn't be an issue with plant-based products. The flour has been thrown away.

Comment: @ersu They are a result of the meat decaying, but the reason the meat decays is that the bacteria are eating it. And what keeps the flour from decaying is that it's dry, imagine living on a huge pile of sugar without a sip of water - you wouldn't last very long ;-) If you want to know more, search for "water activity" using your search engine of choice.

Answer (score 5):

But the flour is not dry if it has pork juice.  Pork juice is only good for 4 hours at room temperature.

If only a small part is damp MAYBE you could just throw that out.  You are still taking a risk.

The safe bet is to just throw it out.  If it is only slight damp at one end or the other immediately when I got home I would open from the other end, pour out half, and discard the bag. You don't want to pour out the contaminated end as then the salvage flour would pass the contaminated bag. I am not recommending you do that. Just what I would do.

The store should not have put the pork in the same bag as the flour and for sure not on top.

Comment: Down votes care to comment.  I should help the OP.

Comment: The first paragraph was good. The second paragraph was less good.

Comment: @stannius OK. I emphasized MAYBE.  If the top was barely damp I personally would be OK with open from the bottom and pour out half.

Comment: Well, it's possibly safer than trying to remove the moldy part of bread. It also depends on how long it was wet, another important point you mentioned in your answer. If it was only wet for less than 4 hours so far, could OP freeze it and then use it later?

Comment: @stannius I would not want to to be wet for more than 30 - 60 minutes and would discard the bag.

Comment: Did not downvote, rather countered one as I see this as giving options.  The best option is discard, but with some the item, even an relatively inexpensive staple may be too precious to discard, or the contaminated portion might be small enough to be worth trying to salvage.  Given this, options are good as some will always choose to pass of the discard option.  They are still better advised to minimize the risks which I felt this answer attempts.

Comment: The problem is that pretty much any movement you'd make to remove the iffy flour is also a stirring motion for a fine powder. If you tilt it over to pour some out, some is sliding down and back. If you're scooping, you're also making voids to the sides to for additional falling and settling. With modern meat inspections, odds are you could just drink the pork fluids and be fine, much less a tiny bit spilling into your flour, but the other side of that is that not beating the odds means your brain gets eaten by parasites until you die a protracted, painful, humiliating death.

Comment: @AlexH. Not if you do it right.  I have a degree in chemical engineering and worked as a cook.  As simple as scoop out the bottom does the trick.

Comment: That's exactly what isn't a safe method. A vacuum hose would do the trick, at least until you're explaining to whoever else is there why you're vacuuming flour out of a bag of flour.

Comment: @AlexH. A vacuum?   No words.

Comment: "The store should not have put the pork in the same bag as the flour" Here there is noone to put the products in the shopping bag at the checkout, I did it myself. I'll know to be more careful in the future.

Comment: If you're going to keep discussing, please focus on the matter at hand, i.e. explaining your knowledge. Statements about other *people* are unlikely to be welcome.